# Having problem adding new ee field

Tags: entry-type

How do I fix this problem?
I've search online and renamed the entry_type_lang to lang.entry_type.php on my cpanel directory
but still I get this error
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/entry_type_lang.php
Anybody can help me out?

i'm using EE2 9.2

Answer (score 1):

I used this add on with 2.9.2 a few days ago and it doesn't have this problem. Which makes me think you have installed it incorrectly

If you downloaded it from Github then you should rename the containing folder from rsanchez-entry_type-0a0e58e  to simply "entry_type".

That folder should then be placed inside system/expressionengine/third_party

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound quite the same but there was a compatibility issue with Low Search 4.2 and entry_type on EE 2.9.3 recently.  Updating Low Search to 4.3+ fixed it.  Just mentioning it as a just-in-case...